# Yii2 AuthClient set return page for Facebook client

Tags: facebook, yii2, facebook-php-sdk

I have a form for lead gen, which just get the user information (like name, gender, email) which can be filled out with Facebook. But the problem is, selecting to fill form with FB redirect to index page. How can i set the return page to some other view or action?

```
public function onAuthSuccess($cliente)
{
    // TODO: fb login e retornar dados do perfil para o form
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => MYAPPID,
        'app_secret' => MYAPPSECRET
    ]);
    try {
        $token = $cliente->getAccessToken()->getToken();
        // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
        $usuario = $fb->get('/me?fields=email,name,gender,age_range',
            $token)->getDecodedBody();

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    return ; // actually doesn't matter, it always end redirecting to site/index
}
```

Auth config:

`'auth' => ['class' => yii\authclient\AuthAction::className(),'successCallback' => [$this, 'onAuthSuccess']]`

Comment: what are your auth action configs ?

Comment: @KandarpPatel updated question with auth action config

Comment: add 'successUrl' => 'your url' to config

Comment: It works! One more question: how can i pass params to that url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add successUrl in Auth action config

```
'successUrl'=>'url'
```

it is an public property you can override its value in your function also

```
$this->action->successUrl = "url-with-data";
```

Note: this is for understanding purpose only, best way to generate dynamic urls would be using urlmanager